# Multiplying matrices of the same shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two dataframes with the exact same index titles and the exact same column titles but different values within those tables. Also the number of rows and columns is exactly the same. Let's call them df1, and df2.

```
df1 = {'A':['a1','a2','a3','a4'],'B':['b1','b2','b3','b4'],'C':['c1','c2','c3','c4']}

df2 = {'A':['d1','d2','d3','d4'],'B':['e1','e2','e3','e4'],'C':['f1','f2','f3','f4']}
```

I want to perform several operations on these matrices i.e.

**Multiplication** - create the following matrix:

```
df2 = {'A':['a1*d1','a2*d2','a3*d3','a4*d4'],'B':['b1*e1','b2*e2','b3*e3','b4*e4'],'C':['c1*f1','c2*f2','c3*f3','c4*f4']}
```

as well as **Addition**, **Substraction**, **Division** using the exact same logic.

Please note that the question is more about the generic code which can be replicated since the matrix which I am using has hundreds of rows and columns.

Comment: Are your values strings or numbers?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty trivial to achieve using the `pandas` library. The data type of the columns is unclear from OPs question, but if they are numeric, then then the code below will run.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(df1) * pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Comment: @SandeepKadapa This will work for numeric data type and not strings, as I communicate in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import panda just for this operation you can do this with the following code:

```
df1_2 = {key: [x*y for x,y in zip(df1[key],df2[key])] for key in df1.keys()}
```

**NOTE :** This works only if the values are numerics. If not use concatenation for strings like `x'*'y`, replace `+` with your desired operation.

Comment: Of course, you can't multiply strings... For other operations you just need to change the `x*y` part of it

Comment: In th example he uses strings but i don't really think he wants to "multiply" strings